# Get a specific tag from xml using simplexml php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML I am trying to parse: http://rss.desura.com/games/feed/rss.xml?cache=sale

Inside it has this:

```
<saleprices>
<price currency="USD">6.79</price>
<price currency="AUD">6.79</price>
<price currency="EUR">5.09</price>
<price currency="GBP">4.42</price>
</saleprices>
```

Normally using simplexml in php for a tag you would use something like $game->{'price'} for example, but how do I pick out specific ones like USD from that list? i haven't worked with an XML that has strings inside a tag before.

I am loading and reading the XML like this:

```
$url = 'http://rss.desura.com/games/feed/rss.xml?cache=sale';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($xml->browse->game as $game)
{
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://rss.desura.com/games/feed/rss.xml?cache=sale';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($xml->browse->game as $game)
{
    foreach($game->saleprices->price->attributes() as $a => $b) {
       echo "Price: " . $b . " ";
       echo $game->saleprices->price . "<br />";
    }
}
```

will output:

```
Price: USD 7.99
Price: USD 2.49
Price: USD 13.99
Price: USD 4.99
......
```

Or get every currency and the price like this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://rss.desura.com/games/feed/rss.xml?cache=sale';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($xml->browse->game as $game)
{
    echo "<br />Prices:<br />";
    foreach($game->saleprices->price as $a) {
        foreach($a->attributes() as $b => $c) {
           echo $c . " ";
           echo $a . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

will output:

```
Prices:
USD 7.99
AUD 7.99
EUR 7.99
GBP 7.99

Prices:
USD 2.49
AUD 2.99
EUR 1.99
GBP 1.75

Prices:
USD 13.99
AUD 15.49
EUR 9.99
GBP 8.49
```

Comment: What if i want to set them to usd, gbp etc? To use each of them not just USD? That seems hard-coded for only using one of them?

Comment: Take a look at my answer again, edited to print them all

Comment: That's interesting, so if i wanted to set them to a string like $usd = 7.99 then i could do a counter and count up to 4 and set them accordingly? Is that the easiest way?

Comment: You could create an array like this: `"USD" => "7.99", "AUD" => "7,99",` and so on. Think that'll be the easiest way to use it on your website.

Comment: How would I create that array, I can't seem to get it to work?